# Correct sqlite query wrong output

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Been searching all over the net now but can't find what's the solution on this.

I have a ranking on my android application which shows which player has the best time.

I have this code:

```
         int newM = seconds + minutes * 60; //converting to seconds
         Log.e("minutes:", newM + "");
         dataHelper.insertData(pNameC.getText().toString(), newM, currentDateandTime, Category.leve);
```

It inserts the name of the player, the time the player had finished solving the game, and the current date.

To read the database and create a table on the UI, I have this code:

```
try {
        int i =1;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_OUTLET + " WHERE levelofD LIKE '" + MainActivity.lvl + "' ORDER BY timeFinished ASC";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                // Read columns data
                String playerName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("playerName"));
                int timeF = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("timeFinished")));
                String dT = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dateToday"));


                // dara rows
                TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
                row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                int m, s;
                s = timeF % 60;
                m = timeF / 60;

                String[] colText = {playerName, String.format("%02d:%02d", m, s), dT};
                for (String text : colText) {
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    tv.setTextSize(16);
                    tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                    tv.setText(text);
                    row.addView(tv);
                }
                tableLayout.addView(row);
            }

        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
        // End the transaction.
        db.close();
        // Close database
    }
```

It works fine but when the player have finished the game on exactly **1:40** and above it gets on the top of the ranking.

Below is the screenshot for better understanding of my problem:

[image: Screenshot]

**Does anyone know how to fix this problem?**

Comment: Its correct order [for strings 11 > 2](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-58b82e0a1acf7e6f80669ef1c066e0f0b30d356c0f62879609) [for number not](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-58b82eb1416d4783d160bfd76bc536f392093933b3de695998)

Comment: What do you mean by strings? But i insert `newM` as `int` on the database...

Comment: `int` is in java code ... Did you clicked both links(and Run sql) from my comment ?(and found the differences) edit yeah it should be 11 < 2 as string

Comment: Omg. I understood better now. I'll check my table. Thanks for this man!

Comment: Show the actual code that writes the `timeFinished` column.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are storing time as text in table. Thats why `125` (as string) minutes is lower than `61`. Try to store time in database as `int` timestamp. Or as `int` amount of minutes - I guess you whould like that more. :)

Comment: I store it as int on the database. Look on my codes. `int newM`

Comment: It is `int` in your java code. But what type has table field in database?

Comment: It is in `int` also.

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you want to store time as a string use ISO-timestrings, which is arranged so that it will sort alright.

So 125 minutes would become 02:05:00 and 61 minutes would become 01:01:00.

This will also make it easy to do calculations with other times and dates.

Most time handling libraries support this format. In Java, depending on the Java-version (smaller than 8) you should use Joda-time. In Java 8 you should look at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

Comment: How should I initialize it on my program? Or coupd you give me some examples?

Comment: It is not difficult to use. For Joda, see here:
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html

Use Google, you will surely find useful examples.

Answer (score 0):

A big thanks to all those people who helped me on this. I finally solved the problem. @Selvin is right. I initialized `timeFInished` as `TEXT`. So I changed the query to `timeFinished INTEGER` Thanks to all.